# Creating a barplot from csv file

Tags: r, csv, plot, graph

I'm trying to accomplish a pretty simple task but I am really struggling to achieve what I want.
I created a csv file for my data set and am now trying to import it into R and create a barplot from it. This is what the data set looks like.

| control | salted | unsalted |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 12 | 23 |
| 7 | 15 | 25 |
| 4 | 13 | 20 |
| 2 | 17 | 18 |

From this, I want to create an error bar chart but I can't figure out how to make it work. I don't think I should need a package for this but am I mistaken?

[This is an example of what I want to do.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFFkl.png)

As I said, it's pretty simple but I've reached the point where I have to throw in the towel and accept that I won't manage it on my own. Any and all advice welcome! Thank you

Comment: This would really be aided by data that informs 'phosphate', 'oxalate', 'uric acid', that would be `dput(head(my_compounds_data), n = 10 or so)` and copy/pasting `structure(...)` above as data.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  I tried out the code you suggested to see what it does but I just get an error message. Are you able to explain in more details please?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite so simple as we might hope. Adding error bars to barplots isn't a default in R (likely because they are [known to be a problematic visualization type](https://simplystatistics.org/posts/2019-02-21-dynamite-plots-must-die/)) so we have to build the plot up almost from scratch.

```
# Create the data within R
dat <- data.frame(
  control=c(3, 7, 4, 2),
  salted=c(12, 15, 13, 17),
  unsalted=c(23, 25, 20, 18)
)
# Calculate mean and SD for each treatment
treatment_means <- sapply(dat, mean)
treatment_sds <- sapply(dat, sd)
# Create a blank plot with type = "n"
# Specify x and y limits
# Use factor(names(treatment_means)) to give each bar a name
plot(factor(names(treatment_means)), treatment_means, type = "n", 
     xlim = c(0.5, 3.5), ylim=c(0, 30))
# Add the bars themselves using rect() with a width of +/-0.4 plot units
rect(xleft = 1:3-0.4, xright = 1:3+0.4, ybottom = 0, 
     ytop = treatment_means, col="grey50")
# Redraw the box around the plot since the rectangles overlap it
box()
# Finally, add the error bars using arrows() with code=3 and angle=90
# to create "flat" heads on both ends
# pmax(0, ) prevents the bars from going negative
arrows(x0 = 1:3, x1 = 1:3, y0 = treatment_means-treatment_sds, 
       y1=treatment_means+treatment_sds, angle = 90, code = 3)
```

which produces

[image: barplot, as requested]

Comment: Thank you for answering I'm going to try this method!

Answer (score 0):

`barplot` returns the x coordinates of bar midpoints so you can use these to add other stuff to the plot using e.g. `segments`:

```r
# borrowed from Dubukay's answer
dat <- data.frame(
  control=c(3, 7, 4, 2),
  salted=c(12, 15, 13, 17),
  unsalted=c(23, 25, 20, 18)
)

# calculate mean and SD for each treatment
means <- sapply(dat, mean)
sds <- sapply(dat, sd)

bp <- barplot(means, ylim=c(0, max(means + sds)))
# vertical lines
segments(bp, means - sds, y1=means + sds)
# horizontal bars
bar.wd <- .3
segments(rep(bp, 2) - bar.wd/2, 
         means + c(-sds, sds), 
         rep(bp, 2) + bar.wd/2)
```

[image: Barplot with error bars]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I'll try this method as well.